# Select element inside a cloned element variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have cloned an element using `clone()`:

```
var clone = $('#orig').clone();
```

The clone works fine, but I having some trouble trying to select elements inside it by ID.
All nested elements have the same ID as the original ones, and I need to manipulate some before appending them to the page...

I am trying something like this for example:

```
alert(clone.filter("#Full").attr('id'));
```

Could you help me on that?

Comment: Side note: Appending this to the page will result in multiple elements with ID `Full`. This breaks HTML validation. You should use classes instead.

Comment: IDs should ALWAYS be unique within a document. Use classes if you need to identify elements that you are duplicating

Comment: Thanks, that is one of the operations I need to do before appending : if I could select from the variable "clone" I could easily change the IDs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you provided in your question works fine!

Just replace `filter` with `find`.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Pkv7S/**

However, yes, you should be wary of duplicate IDs.

Comment: Can't use classes in my case... but find works fine, I just replaced and everything went as I intended.(had forgot about "find" - silly mistake =) ... 

The ID problem is not a concern because I can change ID before appending.

Comment: Great! If you change the IDs, then no problems.

Comment: Thank you very much =) that was exactly what I needed.
You guys saved me some extra working time..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
var clone = $('#orig').clone();
clone.attr('id','orig1');
```

check it here http://jsfiddle.net/3tWks/

Comment: Thanks, I was already doing it.. the thing was selecting elements inside the variable.

Comment: what do you mean by `the thing was selecting elements inside the variable`

Comment: my problem was not with IDs. I needed to select elements inside the "clone" variable by ID, to change their IDs as well among other operations.
kind of what you said but inside...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, use classes instead of IDs. IDs should **always** be unique within a document, and may result in unpredictable behaviour if cloned (if you want the cloned elements to have IDs, by all means assign new ones when you clone!)

That said, you want to be using `.find` instead of `.filter` to find elements *nested within* your clone element:

```
clone.find(".myClassName")
/* or */
clone.find("#Full")
```

[.find – jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Can't use classes in my case... but find works fine, I just replaced and everything went as I intended.(had forgot about "find" - silly mistake =) ... 

The ID problem is not a concern because I can change ID before appending.

Comment: Thank you very much =) that was exactly what I needed. (I replaced filter with find )